# For a dendrogram plot in R, how to add custom text while coloring the branches according to the clusters?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, hclust

I have this dendrogram:
`hc <- hclust(dist_s, method = 'average')`

At first, I was showing it with dendextend:

```
dend = as.dendrogram(hc)
par(mar = c(3, 2, 2, 8)) 
dend %>% 
  set("labels_cex", 0.9) %>% 
  set("branches_k_color", 
             value = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"), k = 3) %>% 
  plot(main = "Hierarchical clustering", horiz= TRUE)
```

I need to add a custom subtitle to explain the samples, like a footnote text. There are a few solutions so my first question is: how to do that using dendextend?

I was able to add this text using ggplot. but using this method I could not color the branches according to the cluster assignments. So the complementary question is: would be how to correctly map the branch colors to the clusters.

I don't know which approach is easier to fix.

These are my trials using ggplot, with the correct added text but having problems with coloring.

```
dend_data <- dendro_data(as.dendrogram(hc), type = "rectangle")

cluster_colors <- c("orange", "green", "blue") 
clusters <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)  # cluster assignments

#where to add the clusters column?
dend_data$segments$cluster <- clusters

p <- ggplot(dend_data$segments) + 
  ggtitle("Hierarchical clustering") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, color = factor(cluster)))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = cluster_colors) +
  geom_text(data = dend_data$labels, aes(x, y, label = label),
            hjust = 1, angle = 90, size = 3)+
  geom_text(x = x_coord, y = y_coord,
            label = "this is my custom text",
            size = 3, color = "black")
```

I am aware that to map the color to the cluster, it is necessary a column in my data assigning each sample to a cluster. I have this column here:

```
clust_df <- mutate(as.data.frame(tpms), cluster = cut)
```

In clust_df$cluster I can get this info, but in dend_data, I don't know where to find it or where to add it. In the ggplot code above I tried to added it to dend_data$segments, but I got the following error:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cluster, value = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,  :
replacement has 7 rows, data has 24
I also tried to add it to $labels:

```
#[...]
dend_data$labels$cluster <- clusters
#[...]
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, color = factor(labels$cluster)))+
#[...]
```

But then I got the error:

> Error in geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, color = factor(labels$cluster))) :
>
> Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `labels$cluster`:
> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

and like this:

```
geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, color = factor(dend_data_s$labels$cluster)))+
```

I got the error:

> Error in geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, color = factor(dend_data_s$labels$cluster))) :
>
> Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24)
> Fix the following mappings: `colour`

The dend_data object looks like this:
[dend_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w83yQ.png)

I have also tried to add colorful rectangles and to color the labels according to the clusters, but ended up with similar problems.

And last but not least, I was able to add colorful rectangles this way:

```
rect.hclust(dendr_l, k = 3, border = c("orange", "green", "blue"))
```

but then I cannot add the custom text.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data using `dput`? Check out this answer about asking great questions on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, have you consider using `ggraph`? I think that might be the most appropriate solution for visualizing a dendrogram. It follows the rules of `ggplot2` but is made specifically for graphs

Comment: Please add provide sample data so we can better assist you